# is there any tool or piece of code to find a dbcp leak?

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, database-connection

I think I have a leak in one program of mine, one is a desktop application that using multi threading quartz scheduler jobs to connect to the database and make some checks and actions and the other is a Tomcat web application tool to do some transactions on the database, so I need to know where the leak is cause my database admin complained of so many connections caused by one of those application to the database user and they both connecting to the same user so I couldn't know which one.
I have searched and found http://java-monitor.com/forum/livedemo.php but it doesn't even download.
so is there any code or something I can do to know if there is no any tool ?

**Note that :** the programs are on the same machine and i have doubled check the closing connection also for the result-sets and prepared statement too

Comment: Probably you don't close your connections in finally sections, and/or don't finish your threads after you ahve done the job.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you are trying to determine which application is opening the connections your DBA is complaining about, your DBA should be able to tell you based on the `program`, `machine`, and/or `osuser` from `v$session`.

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything for me.  Even if the applications are running on the same machine, I have to believe that the `program` is different.  Unless you somehow decided to compile your desktop application to be a .exe file that is named identically to the Tomcat server's executable.  Even then, I'd wager that the `module` or `action` would be different.

Comment: @JustinCave so the admin can know the name of the program i am not that much in oracle admin if so i would ask him ? coz he told me he can know the username only

Comment: Yes.  Your DBA (or you if you have access to `v$session` and know which sessions the DBA is complaining about) will be able to determine the name of the executable on the client (assuming that your clients aren't intentionally manipulating that information when they send it to the database but that is extremely unlikely).

Comment: @JustinCave ok i will ask him if he knows that thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try the tool yourkit. 
https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/

It have a graphical memory debugger in it.

There is a 30 day trial available.

Comment: I don't think you meant it this way but this looks like spam.... if you're going to suggest a tool that can solve an issue please include details of _why_ it helps and how the OP might use it.

Comment: Add a reason, but anyway, do I have to copy the documentation?